# 3 column (left, main, right) site, but smaller devices have main on first (main, left, right)

Tags: responsive-design

I've been scratching my head with no luck. The designer has a 3-column site, two sidebars and one main content area.

Designed for desktop, it has a left column, main content, right column. 
However, on smaller devices, we'd like the main content to be stacked first.

So usually, you could get this working by

```
<div id="left" style="float:left;">...</div>
<div id="right" style="float:right;">...</div>
<div id="main" style="margin-left:[width of left col];">...</div>
```

or

```
<div id="left" style="float:left;">...</div>
<div id="main" style="float:left;">...</div>
<div id="right" style="float:left;">...</div>
```

But this doesn't solve the problem of getting the main content area to come first when it responds. My only solution is to have the markup with main coming first:

```
<div id="main">...</div> 
<div id="left">...</div>
<div id="right">...</div>
```

But I wouldn't be able to style for desktop, since the height of these divs are unknown.

Any ideas? Too much?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This layout](http://codepen.io/bradfrost/full/vspLD) from the excellent [Responsive Patterns site](http://bradfrost.github.com/this-is-responsive/patterns.html) would seem to be what you're looking for.

Comment: No worries, glad to help. That site's definitely one for the bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="left" style="float:left;">...</div>
<div id="main" style="float:left;">...</div>
<div id="right" style="float:left;">...</div>
```

You can use javascript to get the height of the first column (left) and the second column (main). Once you get their values, you can use that to put position css values for the two of them.

For the main, you will assign a negative top position, to put it on top, then for the left, you will put positive top position.